# Width/height not changing processing.js

Tags: html, processing.js

I am a beginner with **processing.js** and I have a project that goes like this:

In *Test.html* I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: none;
        padding: none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.3/processing.min.js"></script>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="Test.pde"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

In *Test.pde* I have:

```
void setup()
{
    size(600,600);
    PFont fontA = loadFont("sans-serif");
    textFont(fontA, 14);
};

println(width);

void draw(){
    background(20, 20, 20);
};
```

What `width` should be is 600, since I put "600 by 600" in the `size` function in setup. I'm running this on a Firefox browser, but I get the same results on Safari, too.

Comment: What happens if you put all of your code in a single `.pde` file?

Comment: The width is still printed as 100 if it's in the same file and only that file is referenced in the HTML.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I run your code, it works fine. Can you please put together a [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'm getting a Code Pen account, but for now, I found that if I log `width` _within_ the draw function, it logs as 600. However, anywhere else, it logs as 100.

Comment: Where are you printing the `width` then? We need to see a [mcve] that we can run. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Alright. I've edited the post. Hopefully this will be more understandable. I'm really new here, so thanks for pointing that out. :P

Answer (score 0):

Think about when the `println()` statement is happening. Think about when the `setup()` function is called.

When your code is first read, you're **defining** the `setup()` function, **but you aren't actually running it yet.** Then you print out the `width` variable, **which hasn't been set yet.** Then you define the `draw()` function.

After that, the Processing framework calls the `setup()` function for you, and starts calling the `draw()` function 60 times per second.

In other words, your code is behaving exactly how it is supposed to behave.

If you want to use the `width` variable, you have to do it **after** the `size()` function has been called from your `setup()` function.